# Why can't I export a Contact Detail report to CSV?

Tags: civireport, 4.6.0

I have a problem with civireport. Since I've created and saved one report I can't export it anymore to csv. First, the export to csv was missing. I've tried this...

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=22773.0

...but nothing happened.
Then I tried this...

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=17001.0

...which gave me back the export to csv button, but now, when I click it , I only get a 288 bytes CSV . There's no data at all.
I've also found this ...

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-4831

...but as you can see it was closed without fixing.

I really need to get this fixed. My organization NEEDS the export report functionality.

Iván Lago

IT Engineer at Engineers Without Borders Galicia

More info:

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

CMS: Drupal 7.36

CiviCRM version:4.6.0

PHP: 5.4.39-0+deb7u2

MySQL: 5.5.41-0+wheezy1

Comment: This functionality works on the 4.6 demo site at http://d46.demo.civicrm.org so the issue is not within CiviCRM itself, rather with your server set-up. Have you checked the logs to see if there any clues as to what's happening?

Comment: What logs and where are them exactly? I've also enabled debugging in case it can help.

Comment: Your PHP error log may offer some clues as to what's happening here. Also the CiviCRM log, which in a bog standard install would be located in drupal-root/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

Comment: Also, on re-reading your question, I'm unclear about your report. Has it been created through the UI, or is it a custom report that you have coded?

Comment: It has been created through the UI. Also, I've also verified that I can't generate a PDF Letter . So PDF generation (other report) is not working widely through the system in general.

Comment: I can't see anything helpful at all. The pdf problem was resolved btw. It was a memory exhaustion, even with a 1024M php memory limit. I've also noticed that I can generate reports and export them to csv without a problem if I do it editing the constituent summary report. But, if I create a new "constituent detail" report, no csv exporting. Any ideas? And thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I've checked the demo at d46.demo.civicrm.org . It has BOTH of the problems that I reported. PDF generating ends up in white/error screen and constituent detail reports have no csv export button. I don't know if we should continue this discussion here,at the chat or file a bug report and start from scratch this problems. I don't know if it's simply not possible to generate a csv for constituent detail reports or I've found a bug. I'm awaiting instructions here.

Comment: I use the report functionality regularly to do CSV exports and experience not problems at all. Are you able to try this on another server/network to make sure there is no issue with your specific configuration? CSV export moves things to your computer, so if the problem is there it will certainly also show up on the demo site :-)

Comment: Could it be a Firefox/Iceweasel problem? Let's see.

Comment: @ErikH I'm able to do CSV exports on "Constituent summary reports", but not on "Constituent detail" reports. If my configuration was the problem it should always fail, with every kind of report. I've tried another browser, another network and even another OS. Nothing works. I've checked it against my server, as the demo server seems to be out right now. Again, thanks for the help and the effort you are putting through this.

Comment: I have just checked on the demo side. The csv button is not available by design as the report is not a straightforward table design like the summary report. If you want to you can set the class property of the report to TRUE. Find the spot for this bit of code:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The report you are trying to export (Contact Detail) does not currently support that feature. That particular report presents a variety of information that does not lend itself easily to be represented in a single spreadsheet.

You could use a similar report, such as Contact Summary, and export that.

Or you could use your programming expertise and creativity to find a way to make that report generate an exportable spreadsheet.

CiviCRM is an open-source project and new features come from community contributions of code or funding. The [issue you referenced](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-4831) was closed due to lack of participation. Community members such as yourself could change this by stepping up to make it happen.

Comment: That is certainly consistent with what I've experienced. Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

I have just checked on the demo side. The csv button is not available by design as the report is not a straightforward table design like the summary report. If you want to you can set the class property of the report to TRUE. Find the spot for this bit of code:

```
$this->_csvSupported = FALSE;
```

and change it to

```
$this->_csvSupported = TRUE;
```

That will show up the CSV button, although I reckon the CSV output will not be great.

Looks like the PDF button is a bug, can you check on the issue tracker if it is a known one? [issue trackker](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa)