# Why can't I export my report to pdf?

Tags: civireport, 4.6.0, php

I have a problem (well, in fact, more than one [Why can't I export a Contact Detail report to CSV?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/553/why-cant-i-export-my-contact-report-to-csv)) with civiReport.
I can't export my contact report to pdf.

At first, when I clicked I only got a white screen (white screen of dead) and nothing happened. Then I found this...

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=24422.0

... so I changed memory limit value both in php.ini and civicrm settings to 512M. I have also increased max execution time , just in case. Nothing happens. It simply waits "loading" until max execution time runs off (and it's 300 seconds).

So I don't know what else I can do. Please, help :( .

Iván Lago

IT Engineer at Engineers Without Borders Galicia

More info:

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

CMS: Drupal 7.36

CiviCRM version:4.6.0

PHP: 5.4.39-0+deb7u2

MySQL: 5.5.41-0+wheezy1

Comment: This functionality works on the 4.6 demo site at http://d46.demo.civicrm.org so the issue is not within CiviCRM itself, rather with your server set-up. Have you checked the logs to see if there any clues as to what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of reasons PDFs from reports can crash.  It's usually a matter of running out of memory, but that's not exclusively a hosting problem.  If you have a really big report with tons of pages and tons of columns, that can cause problems when a 4- or 5-page report displays easily.  Remember: when you view the report, you're only seeing one page's worth; when you're sending it to PDF, you're rendering all the pages at once.

You should probably try installing [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which runs a headless WebKit on your server to generate a PDF.  CiviCRM has built-in support for it; it's just not the default because it doesn't assume you can install additional software on the server.

Once you've installed it (there's a package for [Debian wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/utils/wkhtmltopdf)), just go in CiviCRM to Administer > System Settings > Misc and tell it where to find wkhtmltopdf on your system.

Comment: I can install everything (that would run on debian). In fact I have phisical access to the server. We have our own server with a nice symetric 30 Mbs connection. No bandwith limits, no disq quouta no nothing :D. It's one of the advantages of having our headquartes at the University of A Coruña. We don't have to pay nothing for that stuff. I'll try and let you know. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yay!! You did it man!! Thanks!! To help any other people that might run into this problem let me add that you also need to install xvfb, because simply linking to /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf will cause a "cannot connect to X server" error. After installing xvfb and changing wkhtmltopdf route to "/usr/bin/xvfb-run -- wkhtmltopdf" it works like a charm :D. More info of this at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13292 . Thanks Andrew, owe you a beer.